# How to fill a column with the header of the maximum value in a range of columns for every row

Tags: excel

I have a CSV file like this

```
Screen Name,Sports,Music,Movies,Politics,Vehicles,Media,Word Count
henrywinter,0.12,0.005714286,0,0.005714286,0,0.017142857,175
BumbleCricket,0.081818182,0.009090909,0,0,0,0.009090909,110
SamWallaceTel,0.196172249,0.009569378,0,0.004784689,0,0.019138756,209
Marcotti,0.06779661,0,0,0,0,0.02259887,177
```

Now, how do I fill a column in each row with the header of the maximum value in a range of columns for every row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to include word count because it's always much bigger than the others.

If you read the CSV into A1:H5 and then put this formula in (say) J2 and pull down, it should find the column header matching the maximum value in each row:-

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,MATCH(MAX($B2:$G2),$B2:$G2,0))
```

The result in your example is always Sports.

[image]

(have changed B2 to zero to show that Media is selected).